# AngularJS $scope.foo is set with service, but later on in the same controller undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I have a service which calls API and gets json response. I inject this service into my controller and try to set $scope.tank variable with this received data. When I try to use this variable later on (in the same controller!) it is undefined. But the funny thing is that data is displayed in the front-end.

I've looked all over stackoverflow and I can not figure this out. I have created a plunker example - http://plnkr.co/edit/DkFNE8E9897dSF19eaU9?p=preview

My service:

```
appServices.service('TankService', function($q, $http) {

    var data, deferred = $q.defer();

    return {

        init: function(id) {

            var defer = $q.defer();

            $http.get(options.api.base_url, { cache: 'true'})
            .success(function(response) {
                data = response;
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

        },

        // return promise
        getData: function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    };

});
```

I call my data in controller like this:

```
appControllers.controller('TankViewCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$q', '$routeParams', '$location', '$sce', '$route', 'TankService',
    function TankViewCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $q, $routeParams, $location, $sce, $route, TankService) {

        var id          = $routeParams.tank_id;
        $scope.id       = id;
        $scope.tank     = [];

        // call our data
        TankService.init(id);

        TankService.getData().then(function(data){
          $scope.tank = data;
        });

        // why is this undefined?
        console.log($scope.tank);

    }
]);
```

Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP calls are asynchronous requests.

You're asking your controller to display the result of the request without making sure you had an answer beforehand. That's why you get `undefined`.

Use :

```
TankService.getData().then(function(data){
    $scope.tank = data;
    console.log($scope.tank);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no way to manipulate data further on inside this controller? I would need this for pagination.

Comment: Yeah sure you can. Just make sure you do it after your promise is resolved, in the function called by `then`.

Comment: I am stupid. Thank you. I see now, that I was doing it almost as I am supposed to, but failed the most basic thing :D